# 1960s short story about mentally challenged fellow who builds a disintegration beam caster from junkyard parts

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for title & author of 1960s short story about mentally challenged fellow who builds a disintegration beam caster from junkyard parts. Authorities come to investigate, but by the time they arrive the fellow has dismantled the device & returned the parts to the junkyard. The story appeared in an anthology of "Year's Best SF" stories.

Comment: Minor resemblance to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_AL-76_Goes_Astray, but that's a robot, who's commanded to destroy the device and forget how to make it, before they realize that he powered it with a small battery.

Answer (score 17):

On the off chance that you confused details of it with "The Available Data on the Worp Reaction", as provided by DavidW, the disintegration beam built from junk fits with Isaac Asimov's "[Robot AL-76 Goes Astray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_AL-76_Goes_Astray)" (1942).

> AL-76 (also known as Al) is a robot designed for mining work on the Moon, but as a result of an accident after leaving the factory of US Robots and Mechanical Men, it gets lost and finds itself in rural Virginia. It cannot comprehend the unfamiliar environment and the people it meets are scared of it. When it comes across a shed full of spare parts and junk, it is moved to reprogram itself and builds a powerful mining tool of the kind it was designed to use on the Moon - but since it does not have the proper parts, it improvises and produces a better model, requiring less power. He then proceeds to disintegrate half of a mountainside with it, in no time at all: much to the alarm of a country "antique dealer" who had hoped to use the lost robot in his business. When angrily told to destroy the tool and forget all about it, AL-76 obeys, and the secret of the reprogramming and the improved tool is lost.

Comment: Ah, I knew the disintegrator ray bit sounded familiar, but wasn't able to recall this.

Comment: ISTM that the person being a robot is the only mismatch with the question — and, being an early robot, it could seem rather like a mentally-challenged person…

Answer (score 14):

If you're misremembering the device the child built, and it's an antigravity device instead of a disintegrator, you're probably recalling "[The Available Data on the Worp Reaction](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?74061)" (1953) by Lion Miller, published in *The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction*, September 1953, and collected in *13 Great Stories of Science Fiction* (1960) by Geoff Conklin.  You can read the original story at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v005n03_1953-09/page/n73/mode/2up).

It's a very short story, so I can't quote a lot but:

> The earliest confirmed data on Aldous Worp, infant, indicates that, while apparently normal in most physical respects, he was definitely considered by neighbors, playmates, and family as **a hopeless idiot.**

Aldous starts collecting junkyard parts:

> Young Worp progressed through childhood, boyhood and young manhood, **transferring thousands of metal objects**, large and small, of nearly every description, **from the dump** to the coop.

Builds a mysterious device:

> One morning he was observed by his father (as we are told by the latter) to be **selecting certain objects from the pile and fitting them together**.

That levitates:

> There was a rod sticking out with the brass ball of a bedpost fastened to it. Aldous Worp gave this a slight tug. What happened then was utterly fantastic. First, we heard a rushing sound, something like a waterfall. This sound grew appreciably louder and, in about fifteen seconds, **we saw a purplish glow emanate from *beneath* the contraption. Then, the whole congeries of rubbish arose into the air** for a height of about three meters and hung there, immobile.

And gets dismantled:

> With a set look on his face, he climbed to its top, clambered down into its bowels and, in due course, reappeared with the ancient cogwheel. This, he carefully placed in its original resting place in the chicken coop. **Systematically, and in order of installation, he removed each part from his structure and carefully returned it to its original place** in the original heap by the chicken coop.